# Looking for a reference that explains connections and curvature by double tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, connections

I'm looking for a book or a set of lecture notes on differential manifolds that explain connections (Levi-Cevita connection, prinicipal connections) and curvature on an abstract manifold from the viewpoint of acceleration vector and double tangent space. I looked through many resources that I knew, but didn't find one that followed this approach.